# Module Not Getting Installed: pip3 install morphy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I want to install the python module [morphy](https://pypi.org/project/morphy/) on Ubuntu 20.04.2, but I am getting an error.

I tried this:

```
pip3 install morphy
```

I got this output:

```
Collecting morphy
  Using cached morphy-0.2.tar.gz (9.3 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uygwfbh3/morphy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uygwfbh3/morphy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-uygwfbh3/morphy/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-uygwfbh3/morphy/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-uygwfbh3/morphy/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        with open('README.md', 'r') as fp:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

It worked on Windows 10 though. My pip3 version is:

```
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

I tried this too:

```
pip install morphy
```

I got this output:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting morphy
  Using cached morphy-0.2.tar.gz (9.3 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ICmImS/morphy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ICmImS/morphy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-lPhE0U
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ICmImS/morphy/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ICmImS/morphy/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        with open('README.md', 'r') as fp:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

It is clear from the output that the README.md file is missing from the package. What should I do?

Comment: pip install --upgrade setuptools 

 can your try this and again install morphy in ubuntu

Comment: Your question provides a link to `morphy`'s page on `pypi`, which says that Python 3.3 or higher is required. So that explains the failure to install on 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Linux version of the package might be broken and it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.
You can use the following workaround:

1. try installing again but tell pip not to clean up the temporary files: `pip install morphy --no-clean`
2. enter the temporary directory with the package contents - find its name in the output from the `pip install` command
3. create the files `setup.py` needs
4. execute `python setup.py install` manually
5. if you know what this package's requirements are, install them manually

```
$ pip install morphy --no-clean
Collecting morphy
  Using cached morphy-0.2.tar.gz (9.3 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/user/env/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vluz3ja_/morphy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vluz3ja_/morphy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-vluz3ja_/morphy/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vluz3ja_/morphy/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-vluz3ja_/morphy/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        with open('README.md', 'r') as fp:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
$ cd /tmp/pip-install-vluz3ja_/morphy
$ touch README.md
$ touch requirements.txt
$ python setup.py install
...
Installed /home/user/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/morphy-0.2-py3.8.egg
Processing dependencies for morphy==0.2
Finished processing dependencies for morphy==0.2
```